# Webview content is not readable after stop animating loading image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am building one iPhone application where I have two views one for login view and another for web view. When user enters the login credentials, then it will redirect to web view. while loading the webview from login view too much time is taking to load. hence I used alertview to  show loading image.

```
@interface FocusViewController ()
@end

@implementation FocusViewController

@synthesize txtsecurecode;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize OrganizationCode;

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
UIAlertView *alert;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
appDelegate = (FocusAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

if(appDelegate.data.strOrganizationCode == nil || appDelegate.data.strAccessCode == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"YOUR FIRST SCREEN");
    _loginView.hidden = NO;
     webView.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"LOAD WEBVIEW DIRECTLY\n");
    NSLog(@"Organization Code -> %@ \n Secure Access Code -> %@",appDelegate.data.strOrganizationCode,appDelegate.data.strAccessCode);

    OrganizationCode.text = appDelegate.data.strOrganizationCode ;
    txtsecurecode.text = appDelegate.data.strAccessCode;
    [self loginClicked:nil];

     webView.hidden = NO;
    _loginView.hidden = YES;

   }
  }

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

@try {

    if([[txtsecurecode text] isEqualToString:@""]  || [[OrganizationCode text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Access code" :@"Login Failed!":0];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"txtsecurecode=%@ @&password=%@",[txtsecurecode text],[OrganizationCode text]];

       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myexample.com/AccountService/security/ValidateAccess?accesscode=%@&companycode=%@&type=1", txtsecurecode.text, OrganizationCode.text]];

        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if([responseData isEqualToString:@""]){
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter valid Access Code" :@"Login Failed !" :0];
        }
        else
        {
            appDelegate.data.strOrganizationCode = OrganizationCode.text;
            appDelegate.data.strAccessCode = txtsecurecode.text;

            [FocusAppDelegate addCustomObjectToUserDefaults:appDelegate.data key:kCredentails];

            //Updated
            _loginView.hidden = YES;
             webView.hidden = NO;

            responseData = [responseData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "" " withString:@""];
            NSString* encodedString = [responseData stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@" ,encodedString);

            alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
             [alert show];

            UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
            indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
                            [indicator startAnimating];
                            [alert addSubview:indicator];
                            [indicator release];

            webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            webView.opaque = NO;
            webView.delegate = self;
            webView.frame = self.view.bounds;

            NSString* urlTwo = [[encodedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%22" withString:@""];

            NSURL *url2;

            if([urlTwo hasPrefix:@"http://"]){
                url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlTwo];
            }else{
                url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@" , urlTwo]];
            }

            NSLog(@"url2:%@", url2);

            NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];

            [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

            [[self view] addSubview:webView];

        }
    }

}

@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!" :0];
}
}

 -(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
[self.view addSubview:self.indicator];
 alert.hidden = NO;

 }

 - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
[self.indicator removeFromSuperview];
[self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:NO] ;

}

- (IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender
{
[txtsecurecode resignFirstResponder];
[OrganizationCode resignFirstResponder];
}
@end
```

Until content in webview displays, loading image is displaying and working good. but content of webview is not editable and remaining static as I think I used 'web view.hidden = YES'. when I comment the alert method and run then content of webview is also editable and working good as required. I need to load the content of url after loading image stops loading.

Comment: You should probably put the code in the question, not a pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest show the activity indicator from the Viewcontroller having the WebView and implement the WebView Delegate methods

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [actvityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [actvityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

this will keep your webview Interactive and also show the indicator till the page loads completely

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this. The Delegate is important in .h file

FocusViewController.h

```
@interface FocusViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
}
```

FocusViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Loading Indicator
    indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    [indicator setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:120.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [indicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: The delegate can also be denoted in the implementation file. It can also be omitted, if warnings are your thing... ;)